# Group Policy and Outlook

Tags: group-policy, outlook

I would like to be able to default sharing the user's calender to everyone using a group policy. Is this possible?

A brief google hasn't come up with anything.

(Outlook 2010 and the AD is Server 2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set this in group policy, you would set it on the Exchange server. Here is an example: http://blog.powershell.no/2010/09/20/managing-calendar-permissions-in-exchange-server-2010/

Are you sure you actually want to share everyone's calendar? That's sort of unusual, considering the meeting assistant shows busy time already when scheduling.

Comment: +1, for the solution. Company policy often dictates requirements of this nature. It isn't always appropriate for the admins to question such policies.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. Its company policy, nothing I can change really. Just looking to automate new users + assert correctness for current users.

Comment: @Bryan. On the contrary. It's always appropriate for admins to question such policies. Ultimately the decision is for the higher ups but they often aren't aware of such things as free/busy blocks for scheduling or whatever the case may be. Any time you feel uneasy about doing something or think there is an easier or more secure method, it should at least be brought up for discussion. Failure to do so is a failure on your part and will often bite you in the rear when they learn later that there was a better way and no one said anything.

Comment: @PaulAckerman, Play on words maybe? If it is already a company policy, then that would imply that it is something that has already been discussed at a technical level and agreed. Company policies of this nature don't tend to be so specific unless already discussed at a technical level.

Comment: Bryan - I'm going to disagree, based on my experience. Plenty of company-wide decisions are made by non-technical people who don't know what the existing technology can already do. They come up with a solution and give it to IT to implement, rather than bring in IT at the beginning, to define the problem and investigate solutions.